# Sling server side Testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, sling, osgi-bundle

I have deployed an **OSGI bundle** which is currently using a running FTP Server import some files , and saved the data in the Resource ( JCR / FS ) as provided .
For the time being considering JCR , I have written sling unit test bundle which returns test results after hitting the  SlingJunitServlet . What is the best way i can invoke the test bundle from the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

The SlingRemoteTestRunner allows JUnit tests that run as part of a Maven or other build to act as proxies for server-side tests that the SlingJUnitServlet runs.

See the [ServerSideSampleTest example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/samples/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/sling/testing/samples/integrationtests/serverside/ServerSideSampleTest.java) in the testing/sample/integration tests module.

Comment: I have followed the example , my test servlet is at http://localhost:4502/system/sling/junit/com.raja.work.FTPImporterTesting.FTPImporterTest.html
But while running the tests it hits some server at port http://localhost:8765/system/sling/junit/com.raja.work.FTPImporterTesting.FTPImporterTest.html
How to explicitly mention my test server address.

Comment: In the sample tests that's set via the jar.executor.server.port set in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/samples/integration-tests/pom.xml